# If $|f(z)+g(z)|<|f(z)|+|g(z)|$ on $\Omega$ prove that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros in $\Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let , $f$ and $g$ be analytic on $\Omega$ and continuous on $\Omega\cup \partial \Omega$.
>
> If $|f(z)+g(z)|<|f(z)|+|g(z)|$ on $\Omega$ prove that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros in $\Omega$ counting multiplicities.

I want to apply Rouche's theorem to show $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros in $\Omega$ but I can not construct such functions so that Rouche's theorem can be apply.

Comment: actaully there is stronger version of Rouche. which is exactelly as you state : here page 2: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01093927/document

Comment: Check out [page 5](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.0906.pdf)

Comment: By the way, it should be $\leq$ and not $<$ (or else, they can't have zeros)

Comment: @@  Tryss) Not that.In Rouche's theorem inequality sign is strict.

Comment: @Tryss No, its $<$. Look it up. Yes, this means that $f$ and $g$ cannot have zeroes _on the boundary_.

Comment: @Tryss No, you're right, sorry. He stated the problem incorrectly. Yes, for his version $<$ shows that $f$ and $g$ have no zero, making the result trivial. But the point is he was _supposed_ to assume $|f+g|<|f|+|g|$ only on $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : I see :)

Comment: f has no zero in omega, check that. Also g has no zero in omega. Thus f,g have same number of zeros in omega.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you stated the problem wrong. As has been pointed out, your hypothesis implies that neither $f$ nor $g$ has a zero in $\Omega$; hence the result follows because $0=0$.

But the real result is not quite that trivial. The actual hypothesis is that $|f+g|<|f|+|g|$ *on the boundary of* $\Omega$.

I doubt that you'll be able to derive this from the version of Rouche's theorem that you're trying to use. You *can* however derive it by modifying the *proof* of that theorem! The hypothesis is weaker, but it's strong enough to do whatever the hypothesis $|f-g|<|f|$ does in the traditional proof.

For example: Note first that if $h=-g$ then $|h|=|g|$ and $h$ and $g$ have the same number of zeroes. So you can assume that $|f-g|<|f|+|g|$ on the boundary instead.

Now there is a neighborhood $V$ of $\partial\Omega$ in $\overline\Omega$ such that $|f-g|<|f|+|g|$ in $V$. Let $$W=\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0].$$We have $$f(z)/g(z)\in W\quad(z\in V).$$Let $L$ be a branch of the logarithm in $W$, and define $F\in H(V)$ by $F=L\circ(f/g)$. Now since the integral of a derivative over a closed curve is always $0$ it follows that if $\Gamma$ is a cycle in $V$ then $$\int_\Gamma F'(z)\,dz=0.$$Figure out what $F'$ is, and then figure out what this says about the zeroes of $f$ and $g$.

Or see Ullrich *Complex Made Simple* for a proof by homotopy. (That's the only complex text I know that has this version of Rouche...)